# Option poster in the \movie command in Beamer doesn’t work

Tags: beamer, multimedia

I am trying to get the first frame of an `avi` file show before playing the `avi` file using the command

```
\movie[width=1.7in,height=1.7in,poster,loop,autostart]{}{filename.avi}
```

The PDF file compiled using `pdflatex` on my MacBook gives me the generic picture (which looks like a broken window?) before I click on it to play my `avi` file. 
I thought that the option poster in the above `movie`command is supposed to extract the first frame of my`avi` file and display it in the box before playing the video, instead of showing a generic display.

Much appreciate any help. I looked everywhere for this on the web but never found anyone asking this question. Maybe its a straightforward fix?

Comment: Does the video play at all? Since even `autostart` has no effect, I suspect the AVI of having the wrong encoding. Option `poster` instructs the media player plugin to render the first frame from the video content. Thus, there must be something wrong with the video.

Comment: Which PDF viewer are you using?

Comment: Yes, video plays fine. Its just that when static, the image it shows is that of a broken window pane. This seems to be default. Here’s the code I used in my Beamer file to play the video.\begin{column}{1.8in}
 \begin{figure}
 \movie[width=1.7in,height=1.7in,poster,loop,autostart]{myfile.avi}
 \caption{my video}
        \label{faceTrack}
        \end{figure}
       \end{column}

Comment: I use adobe acrobat reader DC version 2018.009.20050  I suspect the problem is with Adobe reader?

Comment: After trying a lot of things, I found that this happens when I have two videos on the same page. If I use autostart option on both, only one plays and the other shows the “broken window pane” generic static display. Once I click on the generic static display, the second video starts playing and the first one stops and goes to the default display (a broken window pane). Really strange. I found that this does not happen if I use just ONE video and not use the \begin{columns} format. I wanted to include two videos on one page though.

Comment: I even tried what you (Alex) suggested on another posting i.e., using media9, converting my avi files to m4v using VLC app. Here’s the code that I cut and paste into my beamer code.\includemedia[
  label=vidA,
  addresource=facetracking.m4v,
  activate=pageopen,
  width=1.7in, height=1.7in,
  flashvars={
     source=facetracking.m4v
    &loop=true
  }
]{}{VPlayer.swf}

Comment: I repeat this code for the second video. This works now however, the video has artifacts (green+other colors on it). Is this because of converting avi to m4v using VLC or because of the flash player is the question. Is there any way to fix these artifacts? Thanks.

Comment: Could you install `ffmpeg` on your computer? Then follow the instructions in the `media9` manual on page 2 on how to re-encode an existing video file. With `ffmpeg` I used to get good results.

Comment: I was able to fix my problem by using quicktime converter for converting avi files to mov files and this works on media9. Thanks.

Comment: @gatorgig Would you like to write an answer how you solved your problem?

Comment: Sure. I used the code from AlexG elsewhere on this forum. It was basically using media9 instead of multimedia package. Since the media9 package does not accept avi files, I had to convert it to either m4v files or mov files. After which, I used the code that Alex had posted in this forum on how to put two videos on the same page and play them simultaneously. I don’t want to repeat that code here as its already on the forum.